# Automatic daylight savings adjustment: Where/How does Windows remember that it already did the time shift?

Tags: windows, clock, kiosk

Does anyone know where Windows remembers the "actual state" of the daylight savings adjustment?

My problem is related to kiosk systems where the entire harddisk is 'write-protected'. (I am talking about the EWF Write Filter, this is not hardware writeprotection. But everything what has been written is stored in RAM and will be forgotten, when the computer is shut down).

When Windows changes the summertime to wintertime (daylight savings) or the other way around it has to remember that this shift had been done.
Otherwise it will shift the time everytime the computer starts up.
I try to solve this Problem for my system.

I want to manually write this information to the harddisk when the time has changed (File based write filter). But I was not able to find the file or registry-key where the information is stored.
Did anyone solve this problem before?

Greetings

EDIT: To make it more clear: I want to prevent Write-Filtered Systems to shift the time on every reboot when the date is greater than the latest daylight savings transition. Windows has to have a Marker/Flag/File somewhere where it remembers "I already did the shift".

Comment: It is worth pointing out that.  Typically what most administrators would do is, unfreeze the HDD and allow this change, then freeze the HDD again.  I presume you still have to apply security updates to this device right?  If you cant do that consider switching to UTC, and allowing you, to avoid daylight savings adjustments in the first place.

Comment: This is how it works now. But those systems are not connected to reliable energy sources, so twice a year some systems fail... Security updates are a matter deploying new images. I cannot do this all in one night at 2:00 am. Thanks for your very good comments on this topic, your hint with the registry-key helped so much!

Comment: A second option is to write your own application, which determins if daylight savings should be applied, this could be a simple task that starts the service when the machine is accessed by a user.  I do believe that TimeZoneInformation can be modified, by an application without Administrator permissions unless denied access because of a group policy (easy enough to solve though)

Answer (score 1):

Can be found here -

```
 System Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
    Value Name: DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled
    Data Type: REG_DWORD
    Value Data: 0
```

You may need to restart the w32time service after changing this `net stop w32time && net start w32time` in cmd

Comment: This would disable the automatic switching, I suppose. I would really like to have this automatic switching plus "committing" the changed-flag (or whatever) to disk. The whole disk is writeprotected, but I can define an exclusion-list. If I knew where the information is stored the Problem would vanish (and probably help others).

Comment: Does your Reg-Key disable the automatic switching or is this the definition for "It is NOT=0 summertime"?

Comment: @Nibbels - Lets go to the [documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3e5adc56-7580-497e-a972-81d3b25a3e57/how-to-disable-daylight-saving-in-windows-7-by-gpo?forum=winserverGP) for `DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled.  This particular key, "Disable automatic set of daylight savings time in Windows 7", with a value of 1.  The information you are looking for is stored within the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`

Comment: Ok, Narzard, thank you for your answer, but I suppose this is not what I was looking for. [IMAGE SCREENSHOT](https://downfight.de/grafiken/dimi/938e8c6f97da6b208ab5c8d8a4319b02.png) This is the registry key Ramhound suggested. I will look into it more deeply.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724253(v=vs.85).aspx I have a feeling there is a hint to the solution

Answer (score 0):

Computer Time Management and Embedded Systems (Standard 7 SP1)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff794720(v=winembedded.60).aspx

> By default, Microsoft Windows assumes that the date/time stored in the CMOS clock is in local time. Because the default date/time is in local time, the CMOS clock must be adjusted periodically to account for transitions between DST and standard time when DST is applicable for a given time-zone configuration. This contrasts with other operating systems which might assume that the date/time stored in the CMOS clock is in UTC. The CMOS clock does not store information related to time zone or DST. Therefore, this can create issues when write filters are enabled, or when multiple operating systems are installed and used on a single system."

CMOS Clock Automatic Adjustment:

> "When 
>   the CMOS clock is adjusted 
>   the ActiveTimeBias registry key will also be adjusted 
>   to reflect the new value that was used to configure the CMOS clock."

Well this is the solution to my answer. Twice a year Windows learns that it should reconfigure the Clock, by acknowledgeing that the ActiveTimeBias is not fitting the needs:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"ActiveTimeBias"=dword:ffffff88


0xffffff88 = 2^32 -120minutes = -2h

UTC - (-120 minutes) = Local Time
```

(I have GMT+1 which is equal to UTC +1h and Summertime =+1h)

```
  UTC + Bias + (DST?1:0)*DaylightBias = UTC + ActiveTimeBias = LocalTime
```

If this Formula not True: Then Windows corrects the Clock and rewrites the ActiveTimeBias.
So far this is the answer to my question which I was not able to solve for so long.

---

I might have to fix the ActiveTimeBias at this point BUT:
There is a comment and the picture of the Boot-Sequence in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff794720(v=winembedded.60).aspx @ "CMOS Clock Automatic Adjustment"
that states:

> "Therefore, the changes to the registry required to record that the CMOS clock has been updated are not persisted when write filters are enabled (for system volume). Similarly, you cannot use the Registry Filter to work around the problem because the Registry Filter is not enabled early enough in the boot sequence to prevent the clock from being adjusted after it has been previously adjusted."

That leads me to the conclusion, that I am hounting the wrong Bug? Well I have some `XP-Systems` and maybe only they have the Problem. Microsoft might have `fixed the Time-Bug` in `Windows 7 Embedded` but not in earlier versions. I will have a close Eye on that. Otherwise this Answer is wrong and I have to look at another cause of this weired behaviour of the systems.

Comment: Can you take a moment and use quote blocks?  My intial reaction to this answer, before I read it, was to downvote and leave a comment about the quality of the answer.

Comment: Sorry, Blockquotes: I will look into it!

Comment: additional thinking: If I use UTC in my CMOS Clock (And Windows does so) the clock itself would not have to be rewritten twice a year) This might be the final solution to the upperlayered problem I had.